# IHP Haskell Framework: can postgres columns of type int8range be used?

Tags: postgresql, database-design, ihp, bi-temporal

Is it possible to use columns of type int8range?
The code editor cannot parse "int8range". Can a preexisisting postgres schema be used with IHP?
I need those for a bitemporal model.

Comment: `int8range` is a predefined [range type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-BUILTIN) and can certainly be used, see [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/jPHdTri-). You give no information as to how you are trying to use it nor why you claim the code editor cannot parse it. Please update your question to contain actual code and complete error message, all as text - **no images**.

Comment: https://github.com/digitallyinduced/ihp/issues/1649

Comment: Do You know ihp framework by digitally induced?

Comment: Unfortunately, no.

Answer (score 0):

IHP has no support for int8range yet. [All supported database types can be found in the documentation.](https://ihp.digitallyinduced.com/Guide/database.html#supported-database-types)

Maybe you can file a GitHub issue for this so we can add support for range types in the future.

Comment: https://github.com/digitallyinduced/ihp/issues/1649